# Cálculo de Edad, a partir de Fecha de Nacimiento

Tags: oracle

Tengo una consulta en la que me piden agregar la Edad de una persona, el tema es que solamente tengo el campo de la fecha de nacimiento del individuo (`COL_NUM_380`) de tipo "String"en formato `dd/mm/aaaa`, saben que función puedo utilizar para calcular la edad?

Intente con (`months_between ( SYSDATE ,vv.COL_NUM_380 )/12)` pero no me funciona, no se si es por el tipo de dato de mi tabla...

Comment: Obviamente no funciona porque no es una fecha. Debes transformar primero el campo a fecha, y luego hacer los calculos que quieras.

Answer (score 1):

Como lo comenta @gbianchi primero debes de convertir el dato de tipo `String`
a `Date` con la función `TO_DATE` de **Oracle**, para mas información:

> [TO_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm)

Ya después de eso puedes hacer la operación de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT floor(months_between ( SYSDATE ,TO_DATE(vv.COL_NUM_380, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ))/12) AS meses FROM table vv;
```

Modificación de la consulta con los comentarios de @Patricio Moracho.

Comment: Te sugiero dos cosas, usar `floor()` para no obtener una cantidad de años con decimales y fijate que el formato de fecha del AP en realidad es `DD/MM/YYYY`. Saludos

Comment: Listo se edito la respuesta con tus comentarios.

Comment: Chicos muchas gracias! si me funciona pero por alguna razón me lo marca en negativo (ejemplo -23),  quisiera reemplazar el - por vació pero no se si sea la mejor opción. :(

Comment: Prodrias poner ejemplos de los datos que se esta manejando en la columna COL_NUM_380